# How to create a hash table with my randomly selected arrays?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have 6 users and need to make 6 character password with combination of lower upper case, digit and symbol for them but I don't know what to do next.
This is what I have so far:

```
$=i; $++; $ -le 6
$Lowercase1: [a-z]
$Uppercase1: [A-Z]
$Digit: [0-9]
$Lowercase2: [a-z]
$Symbol: [!@#$%^&*?+]
$Uppercase2: [A-Z]
```

Then I have my 6 users in a text file where I need to make a hash table out of it, like this:

```
Mary Jane               fY5s&A
```

I have no clue how to put it in that format. If you could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here I made my password generator. So now how do I put it to `get-password`?

```
$Lowercase= @("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z") | Get-Random 
$Uppercase= @("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z") | Get-Random
$Digit= @(0..9) | Get-Random
$Lowercase2= @("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z") | Get-Random
$Symbol= @("!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","?","+") | Get-Random
$Uppercase2= @("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z")| Get-Random

#Exercise 2:  Generating a Random Password
$Password= $Lowercase + $Uppercase + $Digit + $Lowercase2 + $Symbol + $Uppercase2
```

Comment: You do realise you only have 45 million passwords using your limited set? That's easily brute-forceable in about a second. Much better to go for longer passwords and just select from suitable characters without the restrictive pattern that makes them so easy to guess. e.g. `$chars = ([char]'!'..[char]'~'); (1..12 |% {[char]($chars | get-random)}) -join ''` would give you 4.75E23 possible passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've actually got some working code to generate a password (what you've posted is not), if you put that into a function called, e.g. Get-Password then creating that hash table might look something like this:

```
$PasswordHash = @{}

Get-Content c:\somedir\users.txt |
 foreach {
  $PasswordHash[$_] = Get-Password
 }
```

Comment: so i made a password generator and how do i put it into get-password?

Comment: Run the command Get-Help about_functions and read that.  It will give you all the information you need to create a function from that code.

Comment: i did that but it said, it couldnt find the command get-password

Comment: You have to create the function, using your password generation code.  The help will show you the syntax for creating a function.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would generate the password using the .Net framework-methods instead of creating arrays and running mulitple `get-random` commands. .Net framework already has a [GeneratePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-method that you could tweak to fit your needs. Like this:

```
function Get-Password {
    #Load System.Web assembly (this contains the password-method).
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web") | Out-Null

    #Get a random capital letter
    $replacement = [Convert]::ToChar((Get-Random -Minimum 65 -Maximum 90))

    #Generate password replace characters that aren't allowed with the $replacement character
    [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(6,0) -replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*?+]', $replacement
}

#Create hashtable
$ht = @{}

#Read username and fill in hashtable
Get-Content .\users.txt | ForEach-Object {
  $ht[$_] = Get-Password
}
```